SR830 as LCR meter?
I am wondering if anyone can help gauge how well I can measure some small capacitance (1.5 pF with ~.05 pF steps/resolution) with a SR830 lock-in amplifier versus a dedicated LCR meter such as the Keysight E4980AL
I'm unfamiliar with these things, but my naïve intuitions say I should be able to get pretty far with a SR830 since 1.5 pF isn't too small. I was wondering if anyone has a had success substituting an LCR meter in this manner.
What I am interested in is changes in the capacitance, so if there is any constant offset, that's probably fine. I am trying to read data from a capacitance-based strain gauge mounted on a piezoelectric device. The company that supplies this device recommends using the E4980AL LCR meter. The factory calibration shows a range of 1.0-1.6 pF. But since I don't have any LCR meter on hand, I am wondering how a SR830 holds up.

Have you considered how hard it is to make such a measurement? 1mm^2 of copper 0.4mm apart is 0.09 pf, so any kind of conductor will through the measurment off.

@VoltageSpike Good point, I should edit my question. What I am interested in is changes in the capacitance, so if there is any constant offset, thats probably fine.

indeed, the first thing to consider is your test setup. At such small values, even if you are only interested in change of capacitance and not absolute value, you need your test leads to be pretty far apart and held in a stable position or they can easily cominate the measurement.

Use 'differential' measurements with a little variable capacitor (some pF).

That's how we used to do it in the old days when low frequency capacitance measurements on MOS capacitors were interesting.
The idea is to source voltage on one terminal of the DUT from the lockin reference and measure current at the other. You need a transimpedance amplifier and a calibration standard or two. Within limits the lockin is good at separating I and Q components.

Me too - old days being 50 years ago. The MOS capacitors we were measuring were swept with a bias voltage, and relative measurements were more of interest - resolution was very good.
